# Maps Are not show in Android 4 emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

1. This is manifest file

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
       <activity
           android:name=".MapTestActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_map_test" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
2. This is xml layout file

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="horizontal">


       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
           android:layout_width="37dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="+"
           android:onClick="mapHandler" />

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
           android:layout_width="37dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="-"
           android:onClick="mapHandler" />

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/satelite"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Satelite"
           android:onClick="mapHandler" />

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/traffic"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Traffic"
           android:onClick="mapHandler" />

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/norm"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Normal"
           android:onClick="mapHandler" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
       android:id="@+id/map_view"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:apiKey="sorry for hiding app id" />
   ```
3. This is java file

   ```
   package com.example.maptest;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;

   public class MapTestActivity extends MapActivity {

       private MapView mapView;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_test);

           mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
           mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       }

       public void mapHandler(View view) {
           switch(view.getId()){
           case R.id.zoom_in:
               mapView.getController().zoomIn();
               break;
           case R.id.zoom_out:
               mapView.getController().zoomOut();
               break;
           case R.id.satelite:
               mapView.setSatellite(true);
               break;
           case R.id.traffic:
               mapView.setTraffic(true);
               break;
           case R.id.norm:
               mapView.setSatellite(false);
               mapView.setTraffic(false);
               break;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map_test, menu);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the output only buttons are display . My internet connection is also good

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the maps API key that you put inside your layout xml matches the certificate that you are using to sign the app? Even when running through Eclipse, a certificate is used -- and that cert has to match the API key. If it doesn't, the map view will work but not actually show any map graphics.

Comment: sir the certificate key is correct , even i generated api key 4 times , every time there is same error.

Comment: How did you generate it? Perhaps you did it based on a Market-ready submission certificate, but the emulator is running a build created through Eclipse, which uses its own debug certificate by default: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html (Signing in Debug Mode section)

Comment: sir according to this , my eclipse and i use same debug.keystore , i again generate the key , but till same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Open Street Maps. To solve this, I had to put an SD-Card into the device / emulator. Not sure if Google Maps requires the same.

Comment: sir how to put SD-Card int device?

Comment: Go to your android virtual device manager in eclipse, select your emulator, click edit and then you should see a field with SD-Card. Just set the size you want and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the permission `ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION`. Otherwise the app will not accept the mocked location you send. Also the map will not show until the app receives some location, i.e. you need to enter a location using some tool (e.g. the tools integrated in Eclipse).

Comment: how to enter location , give me some example ?

Comment: If you are using Eclispe switch to the DDMS perspective. There is an "Emulator Control" view (it is already shown in the default configuration of this perspective). In this view you will find the "Location Controls": Enter longitude and latitude and hit "Send". If the emulator is running and Eclipse is connected to the emulator (which it will be if the emulator has been started using the Eclipse tools) the emulator will receive the location and react accordingly (which depends on the apps currently running).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the linearlayout is blocking out the whole screen!? You set the params to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

So it might be blocking the whole parent. would you mind trying it without the buttons and the linearlayout? 
Maybe you could follow this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

Comment: and this could be the problem! try taking out the whole linearlayout. just erase it for a short test! or try setting them to "wrap_content"